# DOS header parser in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, file-structure

Looking for feedback mostly on the `from()` and `printf()` implementations but I included everything for context. Please do not suggest crates, this was an exercise for me to better learn the primitives in Rust (including bitwise ops). Also, *please do not suggest `unsafe` Rust! I need the code to use only safe Rust constructs.* I can't help but want to create a struct of Results and use it in place of all of the individual vars in the `from()` func.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::str;
use std::mem::size_of;
use std::convert::From;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Result};
// TODO: Parse LONG from vec of bytes



fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("HashMyFiles.exe")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);

    let read_result = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut reader, size_of::<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER>()); // Ok means Vec<u8>

    match read_result
    {
        Ok(r) =>
        {
            let idh = IMAGE_DOS_HEADER::from(&r);
            idh.printf();

        },
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e)
    }


    Ok(())
}
/// Reads n bytes (arg1) from T: Read (arg2) and returns them in a u8 vector Result
/// Note: The number of bytes to read is controlled by the vector size for read_exact
fn read_n<T>(n: usize, reader: &mut T) -> io::Result<Vec<u8>>
where T: Read
{
    let mut buf = vec![0; n];
    let result = reader.read_exact(&mut buf);
    match result
    {
        Ok(_) => return Ok(buf),
        Err(e) => return Err(e)
    }
}
type WORD = u16; // aka USHORT
type DWORD = u32;
type CHAR = u8;
type BYTE = u8;
type LONG = i32; // signed

///Size: First 64 bytes of valid PE file
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{
    e_magic: WORD,
    e_cblp: WORD,
    e_cp: WORD,
    e_crlc: WORD,
    e_cparhdr: WORD,
    e_minalloc: WORD,
    e_maxalloc: WORD,
    e_ss: WORD,
    e_sp: WORD,
    e_csum: WORD,
    e_ip: WORD,
    e_cs: WORD,
    e_lfarlc: WORD,
    e_ovno: WORD,
    e_res: [WORD; 4],
    e_oemid: WORD,
    e_oeminfo: WORD,
    e_res2: [WORD; 10],
    e_lfanew: LONG
}

impl IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{
    fn new<T>(br: T)
    where T: BufRead
    {

    }
    fn printf(&self)
    {
        println!("struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER");
        println!("\te_magic: ");
        parse_bytes::print_word(self.e_magic);

        println!("\te_cblp: {:X}", self.e_cblp);
        println!("\te_cblp: {:X}", self.e_cblp);
        println!("\te_cp: {:X}", self.e_cp);
        println!("\te_crlc: {:X}", self.e_crlc);
        println!("\te_cparhdr: {:X}", self.e_cparhdr);
        println!("\te_minalloc: {:X}", self.e_minalloc);
        println!("\te_maxalloc: {:X}", self.e_maxalloc);
        println!("\te_ss: {:X}", self.e_ss);
        println!("\te_sp: {:X}", self.e_sp);
        println!("\te_csum: {:X}", self.e_csum);
        println!("\te_ip: {:X}", self.e_ip);
        println!("\te_cs: {:X}", self.e_cs);
        println!("\te_lfarlc: {:X}", self.e_lfarlc);
        println!("\te_ovno: {:X}", self.e_ovno);
        println!("\te_res: ");
        for b in self.e_res.iter()
        {
            print!("{:X}", b);
        }
        println!("\te_oemid: {:X}", self.e_oemid);
        println!("\te_oeminfo: {:X}", self.e_oeminfo);
        println!("\te_res2: ");
        for b in self.e_res2.iter()
        {
            print!("{:X}", b);
        }
        println!("\te_lfanew: {:X}", self.e_lfanew);



    }

}

impl Display for IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result
    {
        write!(f, "e_magic: {:X}\n
        e_cblp: {:X}\n", self.e_magic, self.e_cblp)

    }
} 

impl<'a> From<&'a  Vec<u8>> for IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{
    fn from(f: &'a Vec<u8>) -> Self
    {
        use std::io::Cursor;
        let mut buf = Cursor::new(f);
        //Not a fan of this below:
        let e_magic = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_cblp = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_cp = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_crlc = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_cparhdr = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_minalloc = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_maxalloc = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_ss = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_sp = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_csum = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_ip = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_cs = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_lfarlc = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_ovno = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_res = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<[WORD; 4]>());
        let e_oemid = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_oeminfo = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<WORD>());
        let e_res2 = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<[WORD; 10]>());
        let e_lfanew = parse_bytes::read_n(&mut buf, std::mem::size_of::<LONG>());

        IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
        {
            e_magic:
            {
                let v = e_magic.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16

            },

            e_cblp:
            {
                let v = e_cblp.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16

            },
            e_cp:
            {
                let v = e_cp.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16

            },
            e_crlc:
            {
                let v = e_crlc.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_cparhdr:
            {

                let v = e_cparhdr.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16                
            },
            e_minalloc:
            {

                let v = e_minalloc.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_maxalloc:
            {

                let v = e_maxalloc.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_ss:
            {

                let v = e_ss.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_sp:
            {

                let v = e_sp.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_csum:
            {

                let v = e_csum.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_ip:
            {

                let v = e_ip.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_cs:
            {

                let v = e_cs.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_lfarlc:
            {

                let v = e_lfarlc.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_ovno:
            {

                let v = e_ovno.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_res:
            {

                let v = e_res.unwrap();
                let mut four_w: [WORD; 4]= [0; 4];
                  four_w[0] = ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16;
                  four_w[1] = ((v[2] as u16) << 8) | v[3] as u16;
                  four_w[2] = ((v[4] as u16) << 8) | v[5] as u16;
                  four_w[3] = ((v[6] as u16) << 8) | v[7] as u16;
                  four_w
            },
            e_oemid:
            {

                let v = e_oemid.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_oeminfo:
            {

                let v = e_oeminfo.unwrap();

                  ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16
            },
            e_res2:
            {

                let v = e_res2.unwrap();

                let mut ten_w: [WORD;10]= [0; 10];
                  ten_w[0] = ((v[0] as u16) << 8) | v[1] as u16;
                  ten_w[1] = ((v[2] as u16) << 8) | v[3] as u16;
                  ten_w[2] = ((v[4] as u16) << 8) | v[5] as u16;
                  ten_w[3] = ((v[6] as u16) << 8) | v[7] as u16;
                  ten_w[4] = ((v[8] as u16) << 8) | v[9] as u16;
                  ten_w[5] = ((v[10] as u16) << 8) | v[11] as u16;
                  ten_w[6] = ((v[12] as u16) << 8) | v[13] as u16;
                  ten_w[7] = ((v[14] as u16) << 8) | v[15] as u16;
                  ten_w[8] = ((v[16] as u16) << 8) | v[17] as u16;
                  ten_w[9] = ((v[18] as u16) << 8) | v[19] as u16;
                  ten_w
            },
            e_lfanew:
            {
                let v = e_lfanew.unwrap();

                    let temp: i32 = (v[0] as i32)<< 24 as i32;
                    let temp2: i32 = (v[1] as i32)<< 16 as i32;
                    let temp3: i32 = (v[2] as i32)<< 8 as i32;
                    let result = temp | temp2 | temp3 | v[3] as i32;
                  result
            }
        }
    }
}



mod parse_bytes
{
    use std::io::Read;
    use std::io::BufRead;
    pub fn read_n<T>(br: &mut T, num_bytes: usize) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ::std::io::Error>
    where T: BufRead
    {
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; num_bytes];
        let result = br.read_exact(&mut buf);
        match result
        {
            Ok(r) => return Ok(buf.to_vec()),
            Err(e) => return Err(e)
        }


    }

    pub fn u8_to_char(u: u8) -> char
    {
        u as char
    }

    pub fn print_word(w: u16)
    {
        let b1 =  (w >> 8) as u8; // Grab high aka "first" byte
        let b2 = w as u8; // Grab low aka "second" byte (right)
        print!("{}{}", u8_to_char(b1), u8_to_char(b2));
    }

    pub fn be_to_le(be: &mut [u8]) -> Vec<u8>
    {
        let mut be2: Vec<u8> = vec![];
        for i in be.len()..0
        {
            be2.push(be[i]);
        }
        be2
    }

    pub fn print_byte_vec_as_chars(bvec: &[u8])
    {
        for b in bvec.iter()
        {
            print!("{}", u8_to_char(*b));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Running `cargo clippy` will give you a very good hint what to do. When you resolved them, edit your question and ping me.

Comment: Also please make sure, that you run `rustfmt` on your code before posting it, so it will be nicely formatted.